# Minitest: an array of strings as an input, returns all elements from the array that are substrings of at least one of the other strings in the array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, substring, minitest

```
class SubstringFinder
  def self.find_all(set)
    result = []
    set.each { |item|
      set.each { |comparison|
        raise ArgumentError unless comparison.is_a? String
        if comparison.downcase.include?(item.downcase) && comparison.length > item.length
          result << item
          break
        else
        end
      }
    }
    result
  end
```

Create a test suite to cover the behavior of code, adding as many distinct
test cases as you can.

How many distinct test cases can be derived from the code and how can it be arranged. I am from a python background and now trying to learn ruby and minitest for Unit testing.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am new to ruby/minitest but I have better options in Python and JavaScript on how to go about it. Want to know the patterns and techniques in ruby and minitest.

Comment: if you add some example tests in python/js we could help you translate the concepts to ruby/minitest

Answer (score 0):

test cases using python:

```
def find_string(string,sub_string):
     return string.find(sub_string)
```

Using Assert:

```
self.assertIn('bcd', 'abcde')

self.assertContains(result, "abcd") #only for HttpResponse

self.assertTrue("expected_part_of_string" in my_longer_string)

self.assertEqual(result, expected_string)
```